# pandas mean column 1 of each different instance in column 2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with list of houses and column 'GROSSAREA' for each house and column 'YEARBUILT' on when it was constructed.

I need to find the average house size for each year.

```
df[df['YEARBUILT'] == 1991].mean()
```

Would you just look it from lowest to the highest year?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to parse your question, but I think what you are asking for is the mean `GROSSAREA` per each `YEARBUILD`. If that's not the correct understanding then please edit your question and add an example set of data with the desired output.

If I'm correct then you want to use `groupby`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'YEARBUILT': [1999, 1999, 2000, 2000], 'GROSSAREA': [10, 20, 50, 60]})

df.groupby(by='YEARBUILT').mean()
           GROSSAREA
YEARBUILT           
1999              15
2000              55
```

That will give you the mean per each group of `YEARBUILT`.

I think of `groupby` like merging cells in a spreadsheet.

```
# Your original dataframe:
  YEARBUILT  GROSSAREA
       1999         10
       1999         20
       2000         50
       2000         60

# Your dataframe after df.groupby(by='YEARBUILT')
  YEARBUILT  GROSSAREA
       1999         10
                    20
       2000         50
                    60
```